# Git: merge conflict and commit message

Tags: git, merge

I merge with Git and get a conflict. After having resolved the conflicts, upon commit I will see an auto-generated commit message containing a list of files which were in conflict. What is the best-practice - should I keep this list of conflicting files for a good reason or can I delete this part of the commit message?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever it's worth, keep.  If the file borks down the line, this helps you determine where a merge might have occurred with unintentional consequences.

Often, an "unconflict" involves judgement calls where the merger knows one branch better than the other (b/c s/he worked on it) or doesn't know either branch well at all.  Relatively uninformed, even if well-meaning, judgement calls can often spell trouble.  Easier to grep which merge unconflicted with those lines in there.

Your mileage may vary, I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Also check out `git rerere` which will allow you to establish a local database of conflict resolutions. Always useful if you find yourself replicating the same merges over and over again.